# Find $x$ and $y$ in a simple matrix

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I've just started learning matrices, but I'm not sure how to go about solving this:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1\\1&0&2\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$ $=$ $\begin{pmatrix} 6\\2\\4\end{pmatrix}$

I'm told to use the gaussian method, but I'm getting confused with the $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$  column, every example video online that shows how to solve matrices, does not have such a column, I'm not sure what to do, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say _solve_ you mean find the values of $x$ and $y$ in the column vector, right?

Comment: Yep, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just proceed with Row Reduction as normal.   If it helps, replace the zero with $z$.  If the system is consistent you will conclude that $z=0$.

Can you reduce:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1\\1&0&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} z\\ x\\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 6\\2\\4\end{pmatrix}$$

To

> $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} z\\ x\\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\3\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: So how would I go about reading that, does the second row mean 0x + 1y + 0z + x = 3? I'm quite confused on this

Comment: @user3739406 By the rules of matrix multiplication, $0\cdot z + 1\cdot x + 0\cdot  y = 3$.  More simply, you have the unit $3\times 3$-matrix times a $3$-vector.

Comment: So X =3, and Y =2, but does that work though? I'm plugging it back in to one of the equations, say : 1x + 2y + 0z = 6, plug them in , but It does not return 6?

Comment: Ahh nevermind, It would be 1z + 2x + 0y = 6, which does work.

Comment: @user3739406 Yes.  Ah, I see that you're being tricked by the variables being listed in an unusual order.  Watch out for that.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation for this is a typo, but let's assume that it's not.

That's certainly something I've never seen before but note that the system

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1\\1&0&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ x\\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 6\\ 2\\ 4\end{pmatrix}$$

is entirely equivalent to the system

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\\0&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 6\\ 2\\ 4\end{pmatrix}$$

That $0$ essentially just negates the entire first column of matrix it's multiplying.

Can you solve this new system?

Answer (score 2):

Multiply out the matrix to obtain a system of linear equations:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1\\1&0&2\end{bmatrix}$
$\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ x\\ y\end{bmatrix}$ $=$ $\begin{bmatrix} 6\\2\\4\end{bmatrix}\equiv$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
1\cdot 0+2x+0y=6 \\ 
2\cdot 0+0x+1y=2 \\ 
1\cdot 0+0x+2y=4
\end{array}
\right. 
\equiv$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
2x=6 \\ 
1y=2 \\ 
2y=4
\end{array}
\right.$

$$\implies x=3, y=2$$ (assuming there was no typo)

Comment: Well, obviously.  But the OP wanted directions on how to do this by Gaussian Row Reduction.